# Consistancy problem with texture brushes in grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

I have a problem with grease pencil, when i draw with the textured brushes, the density (or subdivision) change depending of the zoom or the brush size.
Also, when drawing circle or rectangle, it's all doted even at max subdivision.
I was hopping to put toonboom in the bin and go full Blender but this is a bit of a problem for my workflow and style.

Is there a solution for consistancy in the lines ?

Thank's for reading me.

[image]